Updated p12 certificate file (expiration extended), suddenly getting exception "The specified network password is not correct"
We are using a client certificate to authenticate with a webservice. This always worked very well using:
var certificateBytes = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(certificatePath, cancellationToken);
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes, password);

The certificate resides only in a file path and was not installed in any certificate store.
After replacing the .p12 file with a new one (issued by the webservice owner, expiration date extended) we suddenly get an exception at the constructor:
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The specified network password is not correct.

This works on my local machine and it also works on our test server. The exception is only thrown in production.

Possibly the CRL is being attempted to be loaded from a network share? What AIA and CRL data is in the certificate?
